# How to extract rates and expectations from a poisson distribution.

Tags: probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

I'm reading [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) to try to get an understanding of the Poisson distribution (again). From what I'm reading, it seems like the Poisson distribution is useful for answering the question: "Suppose I have a computer failure rate of $1$ per month. What is the probability of $X$ computer failures per month?" My intuition tells me that I could rewrite the $1$ per month in different units (such as per day) and get the probability of a computer failing in a day or year, or whatever units I'd like.

However, I'm interested in being able to manipulate this distribution to answer other questions. For example, suppose that I have $10$ (or $m$) computers in a network, and I require that any of the computers fail in order for the network to fail. Intuition says (assumption 1) that I could take the Exponential distribution to find the time to failure, $1/\lambda = 1/1$. Since I now have 10 computers, but only one of them needs to fail, that this means, on average, I will have $10$ (or $m\lambda$) failures per month, or that the expected time for a network failure would be , $\frac{1}{m\lambda} = 1/10$.

Finally, suppose that I add some redundancy to my network, so that now I need 2 (or $n$) computers to fail instead of 1. Assuming the above is correct, my intuition is (assumption 2) to look for 2 (or $n$) failures, which is a sum of exponentials, and thus has expectation arrival time $\frac{n}{m\lambda} = 2/10$. However, I don't like where this intuition takes me. To me, this implies that if I have 10 computers with perfect redundancy, such that all 10 ($n$) need to fail for the network to fail, then the expected time to failure of my perfectly redundant network is exactly equal to the expected time to failure of a single computer, because for $n=m$ we have expected time to failure $1/\lambda$. This strikes me as obviously incorrect.

Therefore, one of my two assumptions above must be wrong. Can someone point out exactly what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

**Minimum of exponential lifetimes.** Your first assumption is true.
Let each of the computers have lifetime $T \sim Exp(\lambda),$
where $\lambda$ is its failure rate and $E(T) = 1/\lambda.$
Let $V$ be the lifetime of a network of $m$ computers that
survives only until the first computer fails. Then
$$P(V > t) = P(T_1 > t, T_2 > t, \dots, T_m > t) =
\prod_{i=1}^m P(T_i > t) = \prod_{i=1}^m e^{-\lambda t} = e^{-m\lambda t},$$
and so $V \sim Exp(m\lambda)$ and $E(V) = 1/m\lambda,$ as you suppose.

**Maximum of exponential lifetimes.** However, the mechanism
of redundancy is not quite so intuitive, and your second assumption is incorrect. Let $W$ be the lifetime of your second system of $n$ computers that continues working until the last one fails. Then

$$P(W \le t) = P(T_1 \le t, \dots, T_n \le t) = 
\prod_{i=1}^n P(T_i \le t) = (1 - e^{-\lambda t})^n,$$
and so $W$ does not have an exponential distribution.

Intuitively, $W$ cannot be exponential. An exponential random variable $X$ has the no-memory property, sometimes described in reliability terms as "used is as good as new": $P(X > t+s|X > t) = P(X > s).$
However a redundant system cannot have a constant failure rate. A system that has been working until all but one component has failed is more vulnerable than it was at the start when back-ups were available. (You might want to read further on the Internet by
searching for 'parallel redundancy reliability' and similar phrases.)

**Simulation and computation of simple examples.** The simulation below using R statistical software illustrates the difference between the distributions of the minimum and maximum of two independent exponential lifetimes, each with rate $\lambda = 1.$
From the formulas above, you should be able to compute some of the exact values, using $m = n = 2$, $\lambda = 1.$ An intuitive
explanation of $E(W)$ is to wait average time 0.5 for the first failure (min) and then additional average time 1 for the second (max).

```
 x1 = rexp(10^4, 1);  x2 = rexp(10^4, 1)
 v = pmin(x1, x2);  w = pmax(x1, x2)
 mean(v);  mean(w);  mean(v > 1);  mean(w > 1)
 ## 0.4998082  # Simulates E(V) = .5
 ## 1.496407   # Simulates E(W) = 1.5
 ## 0.1349     # Simulates P(V > 1) = .1353
 ## 0.5963     # Simulates P(W > 1) = .6004
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the time to the first computer failure out of $m$ has an exponential distribution with rate $m \lambda$ and so an expected time to this failure of $\frac{1}{m \lambda}$.  You can show this exponential distribution and rate by considering the probability that none have failed by time $t$, which is $\left(e^{-\lambda t}\right)^m=e^{-(m\lambda) t}$.

Your error is in what happens next.  You are left with $m-1$ functioning computers, and so the time between the first failure and the second failure is also an exponential distribution but with a slower rate $(m-1) \lambda$ and so a higher  expected additional time to this failure of $\frac{1}{(m-1) \lambda}$.  The combined time does not have an exponential distribution but you can say the total expected time for both the first and second failure to occur is $\frac{1}{m \lambda}+\frac{1}{(m-1) \lambda}$, which is greater than $\frac{2}{m \lambda}$.

You can extend this to more failures required for total system failure in the same way, and if all $m$ need to fail you get a total expected time of $\frac1\lambda(\frac1m+\frac1{m-1}+\cdots+\frac11)$ where the sum in brackets is the $m$th harmonic number.  For $m=10$ this is about $\frac{2.929}{\lambda}$, rather more than the $\frac1\lambda$ you rejected as being obviously incorrect.